# Assignment of K-Means Clusters in Python and SAS (proc fastclus) is not the same

Tags: python, sas, k-means

I used the same input file. I also checked the standardized value of the variables. They are the same. It means that the input file is the same. Then I used the below Python code and SAS code to produce 6 clusters solution.  I created a cross tab by SAS-Cluster and Python-Cluster but they are not the same.  I do not understand why they are different.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=6, max_iter=300)
new = X_data._get_numeric_data().dropna(axis=1)
km.fit(new)
predict=km.predict(new)
X_data['Cluster'] = pd.Series(predict, index=X_data.index)
```

```
proc fastclus data= Hydro1.NEW_MATCH_1_FINAL out= Hydro1.NEW_MATCH_1_FINAL_6 maxclusters = 6 maxiter=300 converge=0;
var ACTEMP_PCT
AIDABO_PCT
....
;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: What do the numbers in the image mean?

Comment: Results of the k-means algorithm depend on the initial choice of cluster centers, which is made (to some extent) at random. For this reason the results may be different even if you run the Python code twice.

Comment: @bb1 Is it possible to have the same cluster centers when I run Python and SAS ?

Comment: `sklearn` lets you specify the initial cluster centers, see the [documentration](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). I don't know about SAS.

Comment: @ForceBru Each customer has a SAS assigned cluster and Python assigned cluster. I created a cross tab table by SAS_Cluster and Python_Cluster. Therefore, I hope I can match SAS_Cluster to Python_Cluster.  For example, I can say SAS_Cluster '1' = Python_Cluster '3' based on the count.

Comment: @ThChu, so, `SAS_CLUSTER` 5 corresponds to Python clusters 4, 5 and 6, then? And Python cluster 4 corresponds to SAS clusters 3, 4 and 5? What does that mean?

Comment: Clustering does not have a single defined solution, there are almost always multiple solutions to these problems. You shouldn't expect the results to be the same between the two systems with different underlying algorithms and assumptions.